# Is there a difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'd like to know if they differ in their meanings or maybe if one of them is incorrect maybe idk.

> どんなマンガが好きですか？

and

> 好きなマンガは何ですか？

As far as i understand theyre both asking what manga you like.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These questions are fairly similar, but certainly not identical. I would translate these sentences like this:

> どんなマンガが好きですか？
>
> What kind of manga do you like?

Versus,

> 好きなマンガはなんですか？
>
> What manga do you like?

The important difference is that when you ask about `好きなマンガ`, you are asking for specific manga that the person likes, versus `どんなマンガ` which becomes a question about the type of manga.

Obviously these questions are fairly similar even in English, and both could be answered with concrete examples of manga that you like. The difference is that in the former case, any concrete examples given can be interpreted as examples of *the kind of manga that you like*. Similarly, it would be perfectly natural to respond to the former question with genres or qualities you appreciate in manga instead of concrete examples.